# layout element control in Android

Tags: android, layout, element

I want to layout 3 element Button , TextView , Button on the bar like this

[Button1] --- TextView --- [Button2]

2 button are always anchor fixed in left and right screen(padding 4dp) ,and TextView is center (change width depend on screen size),They should be apply for all screen size(not scaled in larger screen). How can I do it??

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this.-

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that you still need to set other properties such as texts, ...

Comment: thanks ssanto, but I want to use LinearLayout, and I found solution for this problem , I use android:weightSum

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout with **android:weightSum**

Try Like this, By using **android:weightSum**, you can divide how much space for Button and textView.. And it will automatically adjust in all the density devices.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="LeftButton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Center TextView text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Right Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @darkboy0212 if some things useful and solve your problem you should accept the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

android:weightSum work fine for me, I resolved all my troubles :)